# React Redux connect API does not inject dispatch property

Tags: reactjs, redux

I use react-redux to connect React with Redux store, and use "connect" API to inject "dispatch" property to the component. But the component does not receive the "dispatch" property. Here is the code to demonstrate the problem I encounter:

```
"use strict"

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Redux = require('redux');
var ReactRedux = require('react-redux');
var Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;

function menuManager(state = {count: 0}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD':
      return state + 1;
    case 'REMOVE':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

let store = Redux.createStore(menuManager);

let TestLab = React.createClass({
  onRemove: function(itemRemove) {
    // this.props.dispatch undefined.
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'REMOVE'});
  },
  onAdd: function() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    // this.props.dispatch undefined.
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'ADD'});
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { count: 0 };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
          <p>Total count: { this.state.count }</p>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.onAdd}>Add Item</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
});

function select(state) {
  return state;
}

ReactRedux.connect(select)(TestLab);

var target = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(target);
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><TestLab /></Provider>, target);
```

When I try to call "this.props.dispatch", I get an error that "this.props.dispatch" is not defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using the connected component, `connect()` [returns a new component](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

```
TestLab = ReactRedux.connect(select)(TestLab);
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><TestLab /></Provider>, target);
```

You'll run in to some other issues as well, namely you're using `this.state.count` instead of `this.props.count` and your reducer function tries to increment or decrement on an object not the integer inside.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Also thanks for pointing out the other two problems.